# reload REFrostedViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have implemented the [REFrostedViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController) and it is truly amazing. The menu is implemented with the correct view controllers (When the correct row is tapped, it goes to the appropriate view controller). However, I am unable to reload the menu with new view controllers and labels depending on the flow of my application.

For example, assume the menu has a row called "Sign In" that will take the user to the "SignInViewController". Let's assume they signed in successfully. I wish to reload the menu so the row now says "Sign Out" and contains the "SignOutViewController".

Can anyone tell me how this can be done? As of now, the menu rows and view controllers are created at initialization within DEMOMenuViewController.m (in the UITableView Delegate methods).

Comment: I am assuming that you have copied the example code, which simply uses a static array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?  If so you will need to change your code so that it is driven by an array stored as a property of your menu class and manipulate the contents of this array as required

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the quick reply. That is correct. Using the code from the example project. Do you mind providing a quick example of what you are suggesting or elaborating a little further? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this - For simplicity, this code only has a single section in the menu.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutable Array *menuTitles;


-(void) viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.menuTitles=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     [self.menuTitles addObject:@"Login"];   // You can change this later using [self.menuTitles setObject:@"Logout" atIndexedSubscript:0];
     [self.menuTitles addObject:@"Item 2"];

     ...
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
    return [self.menuTitles count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = self.menuTitles[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This code made sense when I looked at it earlier today- and it still does. However, I am not sure how to reference this class (DemoMenuViewController) from any other view controller (ex. testViewController). I cannot simply declare a new instance of DemoMenuViewController, I need to get the instance of the DemoMenuViewController that was loaded initially when the menu was created correct? I am not sure how to do that. If you could shed some more insight, it would truly be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Since you will only have one menu in your app it probably makes sense to hold a reference on a property of your AppDelegate class - then you can easily get it when you need it using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` and then reference the property

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. Wouldn't this property also need to be a UITableView? In order to refresh the table

Comment: I would make the property the view controller and the have a method on the view controller that manipulated the array and refreshed the table view if required.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. One more question and I will let you be, I promise :) Based on the demo code, I cannot see where DemoMenuViewController is being called from. I did a search through the entire project project for it but no luck. Don't I need to find where it's being called in order to make your suggestion for using the app delegate work?